# flashdevelop built error: Can't initialize jni4net. (32bit vs 64bit JVM vs CLR ?)

Tags: java, flash, clr, flashdevelop

I'd reinstalled Windows on my PC, after that flashdevelop started to throw errors while building. Application starts for a few seconds, but then closes.
output:

```
Error details: net.sf.jni4net.jni.JNIException: Can't initialize jni4net. (32bit vs 64bit JVM vs CLR ?)
CLR architecture: 64bit
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6 ---> System.BadImageFormatException: . (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
   in net.sf.jni4net.jni.JNI.Dll.JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs(JavaVMInitArgs* args)
   in net.sf.jni4net.jni.JNI.Init()

   in net.sf.jni4net.jni.JNI.Init()
   in net.sf.jni4net.jni.JNI.CreateJavaVM(JavaVM& jvm, JNIEnv& env, Boolean attachIfExists, String[] options)
   in net.sf.jni4net.Bridge.CreateJVM()
   in FlashDebugger.DebuggerManager.Start(Boolean alwaysStart)
```

I've installed as I think all nessesary soft & sdks. Flex+Air, java 1.7 32bit, flashplayer. 
But nothing helps. More than that, when flashdevelop is opening there are some errors with plugins.

Searching didn't help. I found nothing about this problem.
Need help (

Answer (score 0):

Because your JVM and CLR architecture is not match, Your CLR architecture is 64bit however your java architecture is 32bit, to solve the problem, you need to install 64bit Java

Answer (score 0):

1) If your system is running 64bit OS then you must install 64bit version of java
2) If your system is running 64bit OS and you have installed 32bit version of java then you can use the following tool to change CorFlags value of "proxygen.exe" application.

Command to change CorFlags:   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools\Corflags.exe" proxygen.exe /32BIT+ /force

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/corflags-exe-corflags-conversion-tool